# How to get only street/road coordinates via reverse geocoding (Google Maps API)

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I'm looking for a solution to get data to create a simple roads-only map.

Within a small area specified by lat/long I need data that allows me to draw custom lines between given street coordinates (start and endpoints are basically enough and only from major streets). Coordinates from intersections are also fine to connect those with my custom lines.

Another approaches would be to get all the major street names within the specified area via reverse geocoding and then - somehow - get coordinates for each of this streets.

There was a similar request a couple years ago:
[Get street graph for a game using Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514748/get-street-graph-for-a-game-using-google-maps-api) and I'm wondering is it still a big deal to achieve this kind of technical information in a simple way?

EDIT:
I researched the topic but no result gave me the satisfaction I was looking for. For instance Google's Directions/Roads API are both depending on routes. OSM/Google Maps API are filled with information around a specified geo location but without any technical data I need. To be simple: An Array of intersection/street-point coordinates (are they even called coordinates?!).

I think I'm lost - or even stuck - in terms of my own search phrases. I'm not looking for a copy & paste snippet more like a direction or some hints where to focus next or how it is done.

Comment: The Google Maps APIs don't provide that information (bulk street paths).  Try http://www.openstreetmap.org/ (they do provide that data)

Comment: I was too focused on the Google Maps API because the project is using it a lot. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the clarification of geocodezip's comment I've found the following related question:
[How to get all roads around a given location in OpenStreetMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322823/how-to-get-all-roads-around-a-given-location-in-openstreetmap)

This fully suits my demand to get specific road information within a certain location using OSM instead of Google Maps API.

Many thanks